# ERROR: syntax error at or near "|" when inserting data to postgresql using python

Tags: python, postgresql, insert, subprocess

I'm trying to insert data from csv file to postgresql database but i'm facing this message

````
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "|"
LINE 1: ...e,value,status,client_env,timestamp) VALUES (Mon. | 21-02-20...
```                                                             ^
````

this is a part of the code i'm using

```
...
...
        import time

        import calendar

        from datetime import datetime

        gmt = time.gmtime()

        # ts = timestamp

        ts = calendar.timegm(gmt)

        # d = date courant

        d = datetime.today().strftime('%a. | %d-%m-%Y | %H:%M:%S')

 

        subprocess.call(

            'psql -U USER -d DB -c \"insert into http_av (\"date\",value,status,client_env,\"timestamp\") VALUES ({},{},{},{},{});\"'.format(d, availability_response_time, availability_status,client_env, ts), shell=True

        )

...
...
```

PS: i can't use psycopg2 module

Comment: `%a. | %d-%m-%Y | %H:%M:%S` That's an odd date format.  Why are you doing it that way?

Comment: Is the `date`(confusing name by the way) field a `date` type or a `string` type? If it is a `date` type then that date format is not going to work. Just use `d = datetime.today().isoformat()` format to enter the value as the formatting is not stored in a `date`  type field anyway. You can format any way you want on output.